# CGAL & Boost - vertex_iterator & vertex_descriptor

Tags: c++, boost, cgal

For deformation of triangle meshes CGAL uses `vertex_iterator` & `vertex_descriptor` from boost.
I want to get the `x, y, z` values of the vertex that boost iterator / descriptor pointing to.

How to get those `x, y, z` values of the point/vertex?

The `vertex_iterator` / `vertex_descriptor` are different from CGAL's which I'm used to but I don't quite get the boost implementation.

Does anyone know how to get the co-ordinates of the point using boost's `vertex_iterator` / `vertex_descriptor`?

In the following snippet you are getting a vertex descriptor.

```
// Add another control vertex which requires another call to preprocess.

vertex_descriptor control_3 = *CGAL::cpp11::next(vb, 92);
deform_mesh.insert_control_vertex(control_3);
```

Can I get `Point_3` using this descriptor? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a `CGAL::Polyhedron_3` you call `control_3->point()`.
If it is a `CGAL::Surface_mesh` `sm` you call `sm.point(control_point)`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.